# What is the interpretation of the following sentence

Tags: meaning

I interpret

> [Ever in need of new enemies and a blameworthy ‘outsider’, the majoritarian impulse in any society is likely to be awakened by an event as catastrophic as a religiously motivated attack.](https://www.thehindu.com/opinion/editorial/the-healing-touch/article27527405.ece)

as

At any time when there is a need of enemies and blameworthy outsiders, the majority community's hatred is awakened by a religiously motivated attack.

Am I right in this?

Answer (score 2):

The sentence suggests that the majority of society has a need to seeks out "enemies" to blame for things and that a religiously motivated attack is an event which awakens that need.

"Ever in need" suggests that this is *always* the case, not just at certain times.

Comment: Yes. "Ever" in a positive polarity context (i.e. not in a negative, interrogative, or conditional clause) means "always". It's quite literary in this sense.